# How to display on the fly table based on search conditions in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have three dropdown menus and a search button. When I select values in these dropdowns and presses Search button, it shows me a table from database based on these selected values. Dropdowns are fetching option values from database. The code for my dropdown menus:

```html
<select id="select1" name="select1">
<option selected value="" disabled="disabled">Select an option</option>
<?php 
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT names FROM searchtbl ";        
$result = mysqli_query($sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<option value=' " . $row['names'] ."'>" . $row['names'] ."</option>"; }
?></select>
<select id="select2" name="select2">
<option selected value="" disabled="disabled">Select an option</option>
<?php 
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT courses FROM searchtbl ";        
$result = mysqli_query($sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<option value=' " . $row['courses'] ."'>" . $row['courses'] ."</option>"; }
?></select>
<select id="select3" name="select3">
<option selected value="" disabled="disabled">Select an option</option>
<?php 
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT sec FROM searchtbl ";        
$result = mysqli_query($sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<option value=' " . $row['sec'] ."'>" . $row['sec'] ."</option>"; }
?></select>
```

The code for SQL query and table:

```html
<?php
$count=1;
$header_printed=false;
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","searchtbl");

$select1=isset($_POST['select1']) ? trim($_POST['select1']) :'' ;
$select2=isset($_POST['select2']) ? trim($_POST['select2']) :'' ;
$select3=isset($_POST['select3']) ? trim($_POST['select3']) :'' ;
$sql="SELECT id,names,courses,sec FROM searchtbl WHERE name='".$select1."' AND courses='".$select2."' AND sec='".$select3."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if($result){
while (($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) ){
  if($header_printed==false){
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr> <th>ID</th><th>Names</th> <th>Courses</th> <th>Sec</th></tr>";
$header_printed = true;
  }?>
<tr>   
<td ><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>
<td ><?php echo $row["names"]; ?></td>
<td ><?php echo $row["courses"]; ?></td>
<td ><?php echo $row["sec"]; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php $count++; }}
```

**Problem**
The problem is I want to display on the fly table means if I don't select any value in one or two of the search boxes and left them, then it does not show the column of that field(that search box) in the php table and shows only the other two or one column for which I have selected the value. It increases or decreases the columns on run time. I don't know how to do that. I need that solution in php other that if else.

Comment: Not an answer but you are trying to echo `$row["id"]` but you haven't included `id` in your `SELECT`.

Comment: Yeah, because there is no search box for id and no AND condition for ID. It's just to show the id of the table rows

Comment: I understand that, but if you don't have `id` in the `SELECT`, you won't get any values in `$row["id"]`. You need to change the `SELECT` to `SELECT id, names, sources, sec ...`

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to include id in SELECT statement while putting code there.

Comment: Edited my code. Thanks :)